# HTML5 - How can I specify a fixed width for a particular cell?

Tags: css, html

In HTML5, how can I specify a fixed width for a table cell? Most of the `<col>` properties which were available in HTML4 are no longer valid in HTML5.

Just to be clear, I know I can do `<td style="width:150px">`, but this does not keep the column width fixed. No matter what the contents of the cell are, I want the width fixed at 150px.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `width` on `col`.  Depending upon what you are doing it may also be helpful to use a fixed width child of the `<td>` to enforce its  width as this does not work by setting the width of `<td>` alone due to its `table-cell` display type.

http://jsfiddle.net/ywSvr/

Comment: Width on <col> is not supported in HTML5 (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_col_width.asp)

Comment: @Hosea146 not the width *attribute*, but CSS width on the `<col>` like in the example I linked you

Comment: Ok. Yes I see. Thank you. However, this is going to be very tedious. My table has about 10 columns, each of which will have a different fixed width. And, I have a couple tables I want to do this for. So, creating a CSS definition for each of this is going to be a pain. Is there another way?

Comment: You can use the style attribute on `<col>` as well.  `<col style="width: 150px;">`

Answer (score 6):

Use `colgroup`

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
     <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
     <col span="1" style="width: 70%;">
     <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
  </colgroup>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ***other*** table algorithm by adding **`table-layout: fixed`**:

- [How to set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text/4457905#4457905)
- [previous answer of mine with demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525744/css-table-cell-equal-width/10526275#10526275) (that was for `div` displayed as table but that's the same as `table` element displayed as default)