# How to add CSS Hack specifically for IE10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to add css only for iE 10.

Actually my css is working fine in chrome and firefox. But is creating some problem in IE 10.

I tried this code and made ie10.css but it is not working.

```
<script> 
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { 

    var headHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML; 

headHTML    += '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie10.css">'; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHTML; 
} 
</script>
```

It is not working. Kindly help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e? See the second answer down.

Comment: I think a better question is: why doesn't your styling work in IE10. It would be better to try fix that, than introduce a hack, will likely fail in IE11 and future versions also.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can easily track the latest versions of IE (mostly IE 10 and IE 11) using

**1. CSS media query hack:**

```
/* 
    #ie10,11 will only be red in MSIE 10, 
    both in high contrast (display setting) and default mode 
*/

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { 
   //-- Put your IE specific css class here 
}
```

OR

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {  
    /* IE9 and IE10 rule sets go here */  
}
```

[Read this](https://gist.github.com/atk/4025104)

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WZe7d/2/)

**2. Browser Detection:**

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10) {
  $("html").addClass("ie10");
}
```

**3. Using script (NOT Tested):**

```
<script>
    /*@cc_on
      @if (@_jscript_version == 10)
          document.write('<link type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="your-ie10-styles.css" />');
      @end
    @*/
</script >
```

***Note : I know `document.write` is considered bad practice.***

**Conditional comments (ie10 dropped conditional comments):**

if you want to load external css file for IE, you can use **conditional comments**. But as you mentioned in question you wants for IE 10 and **ie10 dropped conditional comments.**

[microsoft drop conditional comments in ie10](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/).

Comment: @IshanJain i'm not the dowvoter, but i think the downvote is for the practice. If this is a CSS problem, maybe the method used should rethought. Once you go this way, you end up, like in old time, building a CSS file for each browsers. Beside, CC where meant to filter Ie version, this here has no purpose of that kind :). Regards

Comment: @Joe: Yes, you are right. It's for all latest versions of IE (IE 10+). I already mentioned it with answer. Anyway no problem. Glad to help :)

Comment: @IshanJain: to prevent more downvotes, you should state that it should be used only if anything else failed (as commented by GCyrillus). We don't want people to think this is the -only- way to go when fixing IE10 problems. I upvoted your answer as I think its educative enough, but I agree that this should be avoided. Btw, $.browser is deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the another tricks which I used in my project, you can replace h1 with your class or own CSS

IE10 Only

## http://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/

Use this JavaScript:

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
```

Then use this CSS:

```
html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] h1 { color: blue; }
```

[Click here for all earlier version for IE](https://gist.github.com/ricardozea/5549389)