# Is it possible to use a CSS transition for when an element is moved on a page because another element was removed?

Tags: css, css-transitions

So for example, if you have 3 boxes on the page side by side and you do "display:none" to the middle one - Is there a way to make a CSS transition for how the remaining boxes fill up the space instead of it just instantly moving? For the sake of simplicity, say my markup is this:

```
<div style="height:20px;width:20px;border:1px solid black;display:inline;"></div>
<div style="height:20px;width:20px;border:1px solid black;display:inline;"></div>
<div style="height:20px;width:20px;border:1px solid black;display:inline;"></div>
```

Essentially when I will be hiding  / showing different items via javascript, but I'd like to animate how the boxes fill the open space.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So they both animate to be `width: 30px`?

Comment: I doubt you can do it without JavaScript.

Comment: I don't need them to get bigger. Its just if you remove an element, then there is blank space for a split second before the other element fills that space. I'd like to do a nice transition for THAT

Comment: CSS does have an [animation-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) property, but from what I understand, it begins the count when the DOM is loaded, not when you have a click event, like removing a box. For that, your best bet would be either jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: You probably meant inline-block instead of inline. Inline elements don't have a set width.

Comment: Also, you will not be able to transition by changing the display property, since you can't really animate between two display types (not even when transitioning to none).

Answer (score 1):

My original post showed how to animate the other divs to *expand* into the empty space.

Here's how to animate the other divs to *move* into the empty space:

```js
//Vanilla JavaScript:
var cells= document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
for(var i = 0 ; i < cells.length ; i++) {
  cells[i].onclick= function() {
    this.style.width= '0%';
    this.style.border= '0px';
  }
}

//jQuery alternative:
//$('.cell').click(function(){$(this).css('width','0%')});
```

```css
.cell {
  transition: width 0.5s, border 0.5s;
  background: #def;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
Click a cell to hide it:
<hr>

<div class="cell">abc</div><div class="cell">def</div>
<div class="cell">ghi</div><div class="cell">jkl</div>
<div class="cell">mno</div><div class="cell">pqr</div>
<div class="cell">stu</div><div class="cell">vwx</div>
<div class="cell">abc</div><div class="cell">def</div>
<div class="cell">ghi</div><div class="cell">jkl</div>
<div class="cell">mno</div><div class="cell">pqr</div>
<div class="cell">stu</div><div class="cell">vwx</div>
<div class="cell">abc</div><div class="cell">def</div>
<div class="cell">ghi</div><div class="cell">jkl</div>
<div class="cell">mno</div><div class="cell">pqr</div>
<div class="cell">stu</div><div class="cell">vwx</div>
```

---

#### Original Post

Instead of animating based on `display: none`, consider animating based on `width: 0`.

I've done so below.  See the accepted answer at [CSS table-cell equal width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525744/css-table-cell-equal-width) for how my layout works.

```js
//Vanilla JavaScript:
var cells= document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
for(var i = 0 ; i < cells.length ; i++) {
  cells[i].onclick= function() {
    this.style.width= '0%';
  }
}

//jQuery alternative:
//$('.cell').click(function(){$(this).css('width','0%')});
```

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.cell {
  transition: width 0.5s;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #def;
  width: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Click a cell to hide it:

<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">abc</div>
  <div class="cell">def</div>
  <div class="cell">ghi</div>
  <div class="cell">jkl</div>
  <div class="cell">mno</div>
  <div class="cell">pqr</div>
  <div class="cell">stu</div>
  <div class="cell">vwx</div>
</div>
```

Note that when only one cell is left, you *can't* set its width to 0, due to the way `table-layout` works.  You'll need to program for that case if necessary.

Comment: That a really intriguing way of looking at that! Unfortunately I will eventually have more than 1 row of boxes and all of the boxes need to shift instead of grow. (They do "shift" now but that is what I'm looking to animate. Thanks though!