# Why is the width of divs not working as defined?

Tags: html

My goal was to have 5 divs nested within a parent div.
Each div equally wide, and side-by-side.

This is my HTML:

```html
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 80%;">
    
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

The side-by-side feature is working, but not the widths. It's all just squeezed to the left. Any ideas why?

Comment: Your divs are styled as a `table-cell` so it acts like a table. Try to take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525744/css-table-cell-equal-width

Comment: You just have to put `"display:table"` in first div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `table-row` without it being inside a `table`.

```html
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 80%;display:table">

  <div style="display: table-row;background-color:green;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved very beautifully using [flex-boxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```html
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 80%; display: flex">
    <div style="flex: 1; text-align: center;">Left</div>
    <div style="flex: 1; text-align: center;">Left</div>
    <div style="flex: 1; text-align: center;">Left</div>
    <div style="flex: 1; text-align: center;">Left</div>
    <div style="flex: 1; text-align: center;">Left</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
```

to

```
<div style="display: table; width:100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to set `display: table;` to the outer div:

```
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 80%;display:table">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; width: 20%;">Left</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` and widen all elements to a 100%.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper > div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Left</div>
</div>
```